# forward message to super group with telethon

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

Recently I wrote code that should forward every message from a certain user to all groups that I joined but it doesn't.
Here my code:

```
        for message in client.iter_messages('aliakhtari78'):
        try:
            dialogs = client.get_dialogs()
            for dialog in dialogs:
                id_chat = dialog.message.to_id.channel_id
                entity = client.get_entity(id_chat)
                client.forward_messages(
                    entity,  # to which entity you are forwarding the messages
                    message.id,  # the IDs of the messages (or message) to forward
                    'somebody'  # who sent the messages?
                )

        except:
            pass
```

in this code first I take every message which send to me by **'aliakhtari78'** and then get entity of the groups that I joined to and in the end it should forward the message to all groups but it doesn't, I check my code and replace the entity with a user entity and it worked and I know the problem is because of entity, but I cant find out what is my problem.
  **In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Answer (score 3):

In order to send messages to any entities in Telegram, you need two pieces of information:

1. the constant unique ID of the entity (It's an integer. It's NOT username string)
2. the `access_hash` which is different for each user for each entity

You can only pass `@username` to `client.get_entity`, and Telethon automatically resolves the `@username` to an entity with `id` and `access_hash`. That's why it works when you change your code like that. However, in your code, you have passed `channel_id` (which is the constant unique ID of the entity) to `client.get_entity`, not `username`.

Note that `client.get_dialogs` returns `entities` along with `dialogs`. You have just ignored the entities! This is how you can get an array of all entities:

```
dialogs, entities = client.get_dialogs()
```

Then simply pass the corresponding entity from the `entities` array to `client.forward_messages`.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work either.
here my code, as you see the line of code that you write isn't work.
[link](https://codeshare.io/amm0R4)
and with out try and except I get this error : 
   "dialogs, entities = client.get_dialogs()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: I find out my problem now, in my full code I used try except 2 time in my scope, and when I removed that my code worked properly.